# Docker: No frameworks and runtimes were found (.NET 8)

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

I am building a background service (.NET 8) that is connected to a RabbitMQ server and Sql database. Both RabbitMQ server and Sql database are hosted on docker.
When I run the application in debug mode on Visual Studio 2022 the application works perfectly fine.
When I publish the application and register it as a service on my computer that using Windows 11, it also works perfectly well.
I wrote a Dockerfile that will containerize the application. After building the image and container, the container does not start.
Here are more details.

Solution folder structure:
[Solution folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6834.png)

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-LogRecord_Service-2087123f-9942-4cc7-aa76-8c572656e691</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.3.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.3.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Database_Logic_Layer\Database_Logic_Layer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Geotab_Logic_Layer\Geotab_Logic_Layer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\QueueManagement\QueueManagement.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Docker File:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LogRecord_Service/LogRecord_Service.csproj", "LogRecord_Service/"]
COPY ["Database_Logic_Layer/Database_Logic_Layer.csproj", "Database_Logic_Layer/"]
COPY ["DataAccess/DataAccess.csproj", "DataAccess/"]
COPY ["Helpers/Helpers.csproj", "Helpers/"]
COPY ["Geotab_Logic_Layer/Geotab_Logic_Layer.csproj", "Geotab_Logic_Layer/"]
COPY ["QueueManagement/QueueManagement.csproj", "QueueManagement/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./LogRecord_Service/LogRecord_Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/LogRecord_Service"
RUN dotnet build "./LogRecord_Service.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./LogRecord_Service.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LogRecord_Service.dll"]
```

Image build logs:

```
docker build -t log_record_producer_image .
[+] Building 1.2s (22/22) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                     docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.31kB                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0                                                                                                                                0.4s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 464B                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [build  1/12] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0@sha256:9bb0d97c4361cc844f225c144ac2adb2b65fabfef21f95caedcf215d844238fe                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [final 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 => => transferring context: 6.22kB                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [final 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                     0.1s
 => CACHED [build  2/12] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [build  3/12] COPY [LogRecord_Service/LogRecord_Service.csproj, LogRecord_Service/]                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [build  4/12] COPY [Database_Logic_Layer/Database_Logic_Layer.csproj, Database_Logic_Layer/]                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [build  5/12] COPY [DataAccess/DataAccess.csproj, DataAccess/]                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [build  6/12] COPY [Helpers/Helpers.csproj, Helpers/]                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [build  7/12] COPY [Geotab_Logic_Layer/Geotab_Logic_Layer.csproj, Geotab_Logic_Layer/]                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build  8/12] COPY [QueueManagement/QueueManagement.csproj, QueueManagement/]                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [build  9/12] RUN dotnet restore "./LogRecord_Service/LogRecord_Service.csproj"                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [build 10/12] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 11/12] WORKDIR /src/LogRecord_Service                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [build 12/12] RUN dotnet build "./LogRecord_Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [publish 1/1] RUN dotnet publish "./LogRecord_Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false                                                                          0.0s
 => [final 3/3] COPY --from=publish /app/publish .                                                                                                                                               0.5s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                          0.1s
 => => writing image sha256:bc73c757dec2ead70c8db7df5a2e08fe9665e8b0396ab2a141bf590fd449af82                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/log_record_producer_image                                                                                                                                     0.0s

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/default/default/r14olesvrbxevmit01mirf4ev

What's Next?
  View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview
```

Container logs after creating and attempting to start the container:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaPVB.png)

I am not sure what the issue is.
I used a similar file to create and start a container for a console application (also .Net 8) and it worked perfectly well.
Please help in figuring this out.

- I asked ChatGPT about this issue and it kept regargitating the same information. It says my Dockerfile is incorrect and I should change it. The suggested Dockerfile it gave me was identical to the one I have.
- I also checked on Github for similar issues and the proposed solutions do not solve my current problem.

Comment: When you publish the app, is it in Release configuration? If you start it in Release, does it run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is looking for the ASP.NET framework (as indicated by the log message `Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)`). ASP.NET isn't included in the `runtime` image. You need to use the `aspnet` image as your base image.

Change

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS final
```

to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS final
```

and it should work.

In the future, please don't link images of text in your questions. Copy and paste the text into your question. That makes searching and copy/pasting a lot easier. I had to type in the log message manually from your image.